# ruby on rails concatenating two active records objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two complex rails (AR) queries coming from two different methods that I sometimes want to concatenate. The data structure returned in each object is the same I just want to append one onto another.

Here's a simplified example (not my actual code):

```
 @peep1 = Person.find(1)

 @peep2 = Person.find(2)
```

Thought something like this would work:

```
 @peeps = @peep1 << @peep2
```

or this

```
 @peeps = @peep1 + @peep2
```

The above is just a simplified example - joining the queries etc won't work in my case.

**Edit:**
Maybe concatenating is the wrong term.

Here's the output I'd like:

Say @peep1 has:
first_name: Bob
last_name: Smith

and @peep2 has:
first_name: Joe
last_name: Johnson

I want these to be combined into a third object. So if I iterate through @peeps it will contain the data from both previous objects:

@peeps has:
first_name: Bob
last_name: Smith
first_name: Joe
last_name: Johnson

Thanks!

Comment: please provide a more detailed example, because I don't understand what you mean by concatenating objects. I know what it means for strings: `"a" + "b"` => `"ab"`, But what should the resulting Object (Person) look like?

Comment: Edit is above. Maybe concatenate is the wrong term.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be frank, nothing that you are describing makes any sense :)

`@peep1` and `@peep2` each represent a single object -- a single row in the database.

There is no sense in which they can be meaningfully combined.

You can make an array of both of them.

```
@all_peeps = [@peep1, @peep2]
```

And then iterate over that.

```
@all_peeps.each do |peep|
  print peep.first_name
end
```

Comment: "nothing that you are describing makes any sense" - guess you read my mind then :). thanks

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
> @loop_feed = @job.bids.all
> @bidadd = [] 
> @loop_feed.each do |loop_feed|   
> compare_id = loop_feed.user_id
>     @user_search.each do |user|
>       if compare_id == user.id 
>         @bidadd = [@bidadd, loop_feed].flatten
>       end
>     end 
> end
```